# CSRF Token getting lost

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat

I have a Tomcat on which my application is running and now I am trying to configure an Apache as reverse proxy. I am doing this because I want to add a few headers to the requests I receive from a few test mobile devices.
This is an extract of the httpd.conf

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader set uid 123 
    RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https' 
</IfModule>  
ProxyPass / https://localhost:9002/ Timeout=5400 Keepalive=On
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:9002/   
Timeout 5400 
ProxyTimeout 5400  
SSLProxyEngine on  
SSLProxyVerify none  
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off  
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off  
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

The reverse proxy basically works, except when I try to submit a form I receive the following error: `HTTP Status 403 - Bad or missing CSRF value`. I know this is not a problem with my application, because if I submit the same form connecting directly to Tomcat it works. I've also checked with Firebug that the CSRF parameter is actually being submitted. So my guess is that I've missed something configuring Apache.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem: I was contacting Apache on with the HTTP protocol on port 80. As soon I contacted Apache on the port 443 the form submission worked.